# Selection in svg / d3

Tags: javascript, svg

I don't really know svg and I want to select the text of this element (and just this element).

```
var text = svg.selectAll("text")
  .data(nodes)
  .enter()  
  .append("text")
  .attr("class", "label")
  .style("fill-opacity", function(d) { return d.parent === rootZC ? 1 : 0; })
  .style("display", function(d) { return d.parent === rootZC ? "inline" : "none"; })
  .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
```

To be clearer, I have some other text in my code and I want to apply a transition on this part and not on the text above.
I apply my transition like this

```
 transition.selectAll("text")
```

but don't know. (work but remove the other text elements) 
Then, how to select well my text? (I tried svg.text but that doesn't work).

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select this text you create here :

```
var text = svg.selectAll("text")
  .data(nodes)
  .enter()  
  .append("text")
  .attr("class", "label")
  .style("fill-opacity", function(d) { return d.parent === rootZC ? 1 : 0; })
  .style("display", function(d) { return d.parent === rootZC ? "inline" : "none"; })
  .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
```

I would just add a unique class for this text (for example `sampleClass`) :

```
.attr('class','label sampleClass'); //adding to the class you already have
```

Then you can select all elements like so :

```
var sampleClass = d3.selectAll('.sampleClass');
```

Then apply the translation like so :

```
sampleClass.attr('translate', 'transform('+sampleX+','+samplyY')';
```

So your code would look like :

```
var text = svg.selectAll("text")
      .data(nodes)
      .enter()  
      .append("text")
      .attr("class", "label sampleClass")
      .style("fill-opacity", function(d) { return d.parent === rootZC ? 1 : 0; })
      .style("display", function(d) { return d.parent === rootZC ? "inline" : "none"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

var sampleClass = d3.selectAll('.sampleClass');

sampleClass.attr('translate', 'transform('+sampleX+','+samplyY')';
```